Chain of convergence of random variables
Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be two sequences of random variables. If $P(X_i\neq Y_i \text{ i.o.})=0$ and $n^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \to Z $ in distribution, can I conclude that  $n^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \to Z $ in distribution?

Suggestion: Try writing $X_i=Y_i+(X_i-Y_i)$

Denote $\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ by $S_n$ and $T_n$ respectively. If we are able to show that $\frac{S_n - T_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ with probability $1$, it then follows by $\frac{T_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to Z$ in distribution and Slutsky's theorem that $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to Z$ in distribution.
To show that $\frac{S_n - T_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ with probability $1$, note that $P(X_i \neq Y_i \text{ i.o.}) = 0$ is a shorthand for
\begin{align*}
P\left[\limsup_i\{X_i \neq Y_i\}\right] := P\left[\bigcap_{j = 1}^\infty\bigcup_{i = j}^\infty\{X_i \neq Y_i\}\right] = 0.
\end{align*}
Taking complement, this is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
P\left[\bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty\bigcap_{i = j}^\infty\{X_i = Y_i\}\right] =: 
P\left[\liminf_i\{X_i = Y_i\}\right] = 1. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
$\eqref{1}$ says that there exists an event $A$ with $P(A) = 1$ such that for each $\omega \in A$, there exists $j > 0$ such that for all $i \geq j$, it holds that
$X_i(\omega) = Y_i(\omega)$. It then follows that for every $n > j$:
\begin{align*}
& \frac{S_n(\omega) - T_n(\omega)}{\sqrt{n}} \\ 
=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i = 1}^j(X_i(\omega) - Y_i(\omega)) + 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i = j + 1}^n(X_i(\omega) - Y_i(\omega)) \\
=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i = 1}^j(X_i(\omega) - Y_i(\omega)). \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
Since $j$ is finite, the right hand side of $\eqref{2}$ converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. This shows that for every $\omega \in A$, $\frac{S_n(\omega) - T_n(\omega)}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, which is amount to say $\frac{S_n - T_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ with probability $1$.
The above argument is widely used in developing convergence theorems in asymptotic theory: for example, in proving the strong law of large numbers (cf. Theorem 22.1 in Probability and Measures (3rd edition) by Patrick Billingsley) where $X_i$ is taken as the original i.i.d. random variables while $Y_i$ is taken to be the truncated version of $X_i$.
